# Python, Lost Connection to SQL Database, Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

```
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at '(my_connection)', system error: Connection not available.
```

I get the above error when I run my code. I'm trying to send data to the table in MySQL, but it said connection was lost, but I was able to connect just fine in MySQL Workbench. I found that when I removed the code: "cursor.execute(sql)" , it would work again (in other words when I don't try to add stuff to the table, the other parts of the code would work fine. The thing that is most troublesome is 'sql' near the bottom. Please help!

```
 import requests
import mysql.connector
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='',
    database='',
    user='',
    password='')

cursor=conn.cursor()
try:
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE books (\
                Discount varchar (20) NULL,\
                Original_Price varchar (20) NULL,\
                Price varchar (20) NOT NULL,\
                Format varchar (20) NOT NULL,\
                Publish_Date varchar (45) NOT NULL,\
                Rating varchar (5) NOT NULL,\
                Author varchar (45) NOT NULL,\
                Book_Title varchar (100) NOT NULL,\
                Book_ID INT PK NOT NULL");         
except:
    print("The table is already made.")

def crawl(page):
    url = "https://www.bookdepository.com/category/352/Science-Fiction/browse/viewmode/all?page="+str(page)
    html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
    
    results = soup.find(class_='tab search')
    books = results.find_all(class_='book-item')
    for book in books:
        price = 0
        old_price = 0
        discount = 0
        book_id = 0
        title = book.find(class_='title').text.strip()
        author = book.find(class_='author').text.strip()
        # in case there is no rating on a book
        if len(book.find('div','rating-wrap').findAll('span', 'full-star')) == None:
            pass
        else: rating = len(book.find('div','rating-wrap').findAll('span', 'full-star'))
            
        publish_date = book.find(class_='published').text.strip()
        format = book.find(class_='format').text.strip()
        
        if book.find(class_='sale-price') == None:
            pass
        else:
            price = book.find(class_='sale-price').text.strip()

        if book.find(class_='rrp') == None:
            pass
        else:
            old_price = book.find(class_='rrp').text.strip()
            
        if book.find(class_='price-save') == None:
            pass
        else:
            discount = book.find(class_='price-save').text.strip()
        book_id += x            
     
    sql = "INSERT INTO books ("'book_id', 'book_title', 'author', 'rating', 'publish_date', 'format', 'price', 'original_price', 'discount'") VALUES ('"+str(book_id)+"','"+title+"','"+author+"','"+str(rating)+"','"+publish_date+"','"+format+"','"+str(price)+"','"+str(old_price)+"','"+str(discount)+"')"
    print(sql)
    cursor.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
    
for x in range(1, 9900):
    crawl(x)
    
conn.close()
```

Comment: `format = book.find(class_='format').text.strip()` replace to  `book_format = book.find(class_='format').text.strip()` then `sql = f'INSERT INTO books VALUES ({book_id}, {title}, {num}, {author}, {publish_date}, {book_format}, {price}, {old_price}, {discount})'`

Comment: thank you for responding. I tried what you suggested, but it gave me another error now: "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '}, {title}, {author}, {rating}, {publish_date}, {book_format}, {price}, {old_pri' at line 1" .  I will try to see what this means

Comment: I found what you wanted created interesting and I created my own code about it, its different at yours but if you are interested you can take a look. it take the info and write a table in pandas later you can query the results in sql lenguaje. if you have strong interest in mysql from pandas to mysql you can easely deploy the dataframe.
here is the code: https://github.com/Enrique1987/web_scrapy/blob/master/01_Beautiful_Soup/01_02_BeatifulSoup_Books_df_query.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

At least your value of:

```
book_id += x
```

its wrong.
I thing with "x" you want to mean is the page_number, but in your function declaraton the "x" value is "page":

```
def crawl(page):
```

so your unique id should be:

```
book_id += page
```

Its always a good practice to make a print of your sql-query to ensure that what you are trying to insert make sense to the sql-lenguaje.